# Access Object that is in an interleaved Array

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an array with Cars saved as Objects in Java which stores another array, it is built up like this:

Array Cars:

```
 - (Array)Car1
   - Color
   - Price
 - (Array)Car2
   - Color
   - Price
 - (Array)Car3
   - Color
   - Price
```

the simplified code looks like this:

```
String color = "yyy";
String price = "xxx";

String[] Car1 = { color, price };
String[] Car2 = { color, price };
String[] Car3 = { color, price };

String[][] Cars = { Car1, Car2, Car3 };
```

Now how can I access an interleaved Object like Color of `Car1` through the array `Cars` now?

I tried to use a Loop within a Loop for this but I couldn't get the right solution.

edit: I know that it would be a far better solution to use a Car class but I am interested in the way how it would work with an interleaved array like this.

Comment: Why aren't the color and price properties of the `Car` class?

Comment: Instead of using String arrays, use classes to represent the data.

Comment: look at the edit

Comment: `Cars[0][1]` would be the correct answer for the question in its current form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you create one class for Car and work with the attributes you need:

```
public class Car{
    private String color;
    private String price;

    //constructor, getter and setters
}
```

But, if you realy need in the way you asked, you can use:

```
Cars.get(indexOfCar).get(indexOfList);
  |        |              |
  |        |              |> Which String of the List you need
  |        |       
  |        |> Which Car you need of Cars (Car1, Car2, Car3)
  |   
  |> The List name
```

Or, if you need to do it with static array, you can in the same way:

```
Cars[indexOfCar][indexOfList];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like the class below to represent your cars. Then a Car array will do the job.

```
public class Car {
    private String color;
    private Double price;
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    } 

}
```

Comment: No reason to use `Double` here. The primitive is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to access the property of a car you would need to do something like

```
Cars.get(<car index>).get(<property index>)
```

e.g. for the color of Car1

```
String colorOfCar1 = Cars.get(0).get(0)
```

Comment: Have you noticed that `Cars` is an Array, not a List? Well, the "ArrayList" all over the question may be misleading... I will suggest an edit.